# How to force an activity to close before it starts ?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I'm doing an alarm application and I'm using a method to start an activity in specific time,
and I have an option in my application which called enable\disable and I do not want the alarm to open the activity (which play the sound and having an image I've chosen) when I check the disable box! 
So I'm looking for a way to close the activity before it starts & do not make any display on the screen to show that the activity is starting and closing!
I'm using this method for opening specific activity in specific time

```
     Intent myIntent = new Intent(SharedPrefs.this,MainPhoto.class);
     pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainPhoto.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
     AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()+10000);
     alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Any help in this?

Comment: You might want to deal with your alarms in a better way: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canceling the alarm is the probably the best solution here.

There may be some rare cases where you don't know until after the activity is already called.  In these cases just call `finish()` before `setContentView`

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (/* Check here if valid */) {
            finish();
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.some_layout);
            /* Actually do your initialization. */
        }
    }
```

Comment: dose finish() ; do not show on the screen the activity is going to open and it close quickly ?
cuz i d`not want the user to feel of this !

Comment: @MostafaAbdElRazek The visible lifetime of an activity starts and ends in `onStart()` and `onStop()`... anything before and after that the activity isn't visible to the user. If you `finish()` in `onCreate()`, then `onStart()` all other lifecycle methods except for `onDestroy()` (i.e. `onStart()`, `onResume()`, etc.) will not be called. So no, it won't be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

how about [**cancelling the alarm**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel%28android.app.PendingIntent%29) , or using a service that will be opened instead of an activity , that will check if it needs to open the activity or not?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having the checkbox as a shared preference, then before you fire off the intent to the new activity, check to see if it's disabled or not... If however you do want to start the new activity, check whether the checkbox is checked, and if so, call finish();

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (Checkbox.checked())
        finish();
}
```

Hope this helps :)